# What is the correct way to set LOCATION of local Azure emulator storage?

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Setting the location of Azure blob URL has no problem. For example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE YourDataSource WITH
(
     TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
     LOCATION = 'https://yourazurestorage.blob.core.windows.net',
     CREDENTIAL = [YourSasCredential]
)

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE FormatFilesDataSource WITH
(
     TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
     LOCATION = 'https://yourazurestorage.blob.core.windows.net',
     CREDENTIAL = [FormatFilesCredential]
)
```

But if we set LOCATION of local Azure emulator, I keep on getting

> Bad or inaccessible location specified in external data source

For example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE YourDataSource WITH
(
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1',
    CREDENTIAL = [YourSasCredential]
)

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE FormatFilesDataSource WITH
(
      TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
      LOCATION = 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1',
      CREDENTIAL = [FormatFilesCredential]
)
```

Query in order to test this is

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'folder/file.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = 'YourDataSource',
    FIRSTROW=2,
    FORMATFILE='format-files/format.fmt',
    FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE='FormatFilesDataSource'
) AS DataFile
```

Comment: Based on the information provided [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/486505a6-a01e-4a13-a61b-6aefc6b311b8/external-connection-storage-emulator?forum=windowsazuredata), it looks like that you would need an actual storage account.

Comment: What emulator are you running?